# jQuery call function if Enter hit

Tags: jquery

I am calling a function on button click code is given blow:

```
<input type="button" value="Search" id="go" />

$("#go").click(function ()
{
...
});
```

now I catch if user hit <kbd>enter</kbd> key from keyboard by this function:

```
$("#s").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    }
});
```

but how could I call

```
$("#go").click(function ()
    {
    ...
    });
```

both if user hits <kbd>enter</kbd> key & on click **GO** button?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Trigger the click handler explicitly:

```
$("#s").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert('You pressed enter!');
    $("#go").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: May want to modify: `e.which === 13`

Comment: Why? `e.which` is always a number, so type juggling isn't an issue. I'm not anal about using `===` all the time.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `keyup` event :

```
$("#s").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $("#go").click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
     $("#s").keypress(function(e) {

         if(e.which == 13) {
             e.preventDefault();
             $("#go").click();
          }
    });
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jRzkD/)

Answer (score 0):

Use both click event and mouse event: I affraid, you have not mention textbox there, so I suppose you do both on button.

```
$("#go").keypress(function(e) {

  //Event.which == 1 mouse click left and event. which == 13 is enter key.
   if(e.which == 13 || e.which == 1 ) {
      alert('You pressed enter or clicked left mouse');
   }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).on("keyup", "#s", function (e) {

      if (e.which == 13) // the enter key ascii code
        {
         alert('You pressed enter!');

         $(document).on("click", "#go", function (e) {
             alert('button clicked!');
          }
        }
        
  });
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer

Comment: by using jQuery you can do easily event synchronously. Here, the button click waits for enter button click it will call only after pressing the enter button.